# How to render dynamic components in Angular 13 or higher

Tags: javascript, angular, dynamic

I'm working on an Angular 13 project, and I need to render dynamic components. The component template and the biz logic come from the server-side as a string. I read that you can't create templates dynamically in Angular 13, as any component must be compiled by Angular at build time, and Angular apps do not ship with the JIT compiler.

This is only for one part of the application where I allow customers to build their custom dashboards.

It was possible to do that in Angular 12, but in Angular 13 the compiler service is no longer exposed.

Code working in Angular 12:

Template:

```
<div>
   <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="component"></ng-container>
</div>
```

Component:

```
import { Compiler, Component, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
    @Component({
       selector: 'my-lab',
       templateUrl: './lab.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./lab.component.scss'],
    })
        export class LabComponent implements OnInit {
           component: any
           constructor(private compiler: Compiler) {}
        
           async ngOnInit() {
              const componentClass = class {
                 public testing = {
                    name: 'yago',
                 }
              }
              const imports = (this.component = await this.compile({
                 template: `<div>Testing here {{ testing | json}}</div>`,
                 componentClass,
                 imports: [CommonsModule],
              }))
           }
        
           async compile(input: any) {
              const { template, componentClass, imports } = input
              const templateCompoment = Component({ template })(componentClass)
        
              const module = NgModule({
                 declarations: [templateCompoment],
                 exports: [templateCompoment],
                 imports: [...imports],
              })(class {})
        
              const compiledModule = await this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)
              return templateCompoment
           }
        }
```

I wonder if you need to use a different set of APIs in Angular 13 or higher to be able to do this. Has anyone done this?

Comment: I'm curious if there is a simpl-ish way to accomplish this, but I fear that the code required to compile a string to an Angular template is far from trivial. If you can, you should try to make the component a configuration object and avoid JIT. If you cannot, then I'm very curious how can this be done. You're describing a plugin architecture (the "plugin" is compiled after the app build) and AFAICT it's an Angular Holy Grail.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @A.Chiesa. I downgraded to Angular 12 and I was able to use the compile API. There's a project example that I followed: https://github.com/johncrim/angular-dynamic-styleguide. My question still remains open. Is it possible to do something similar with Angular 13?

Comment: in angular.json set "aot": false  & "production": {
              "buildOptimizer": false ...}